# How to get real URL not redirect URL using python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I get the URL for any business, coz this link that I got as output after I scraped but doesn't seem to work so I tried trimming, but I need a URL something like this?

'''https://www.facebook.com/bespokecatering.sydney'''

```
p= '/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/bespokecatering.sydney/videos/lockdown-does-not-mean-unfulfilled-cravings-order-our-weekly-favorites-order-her/892336708293067/%3Fextid%3DSEO----&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjTv6ueseHyAhUHb30KHYTYABwQuAJ6BAgEEAI&usg=AOvVaw0t_X8a-7BUi699tTtT9Av4'
j= p.split('/url?q=')[1]
j
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use `urllib.parse` module: parse this url fragment with `urlparse` and fetch the `url` param value using `parse_qs` .

python 3:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

p = "/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/bespokecatering.sydney/videos/lockdown-does-not-mean-unfulfilled-cravings-order-our-weekly-favorites-order-her/892336708293067/%3Fextid%3DSEO----&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjTv6ueseHyAhUHb30KHYTYABwQuAJ6BAgEEAI&usg=AOvVaw0t_X8a-7BUi699tTtT9Av4"
url = parse_qs(urlparse(p).query)["q"][0]
print(url)
```

output:

```
https://www.facebook.com/bespokecatering.sydney/videos/lockdown-does-not-mean-unfulfilled-cravings-order-our-weekly-favorites-order-her/892336708293067/?extid=SEO----
```

Another one is to use re module (regular expressions):

```
import re

p = "/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/bespokecatering.sydney/videos/lockdown-does-not-mean-unfulfilled-cravings-order-our-weekly-favorites-order-her/892336708293067/%3Fextid%3DSEO----&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjTv6ueseHyAhUHb30KHYTYABwQuAJ6BAgEEAI&usg=AOvVaw0t_X8a-7BUi699tTtT9Av4"

url = re.search(r"[?|&]q=([^&]+)&", p).group(1)
print(url)
```

or w/o the module (though it might work only for this specific example):

```
p = "/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/bespokecatering.sydney/videos/lockdown-does-not-mean-unfulfilled-cravings-order-our-weekly-favorites-order-her/892336708293067/%3Fextid%3DSEO----&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjTv6ueseHyAhUHb30KHYTYABwQuAJ6BAgEEAI&usg=AOvVaw0t_X8a-7BUi699tTtT9Av4"
url = p.split("q=")[1].split("&")[0]
print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
j = p.split('=')[1]
k=  '/'.join(j.split('/')[0:2])
print(k)
```

Comment: I have tried your code, But i didn't seem to work for all URLs                                                          div = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'kCrYT'})
for w in div:
    for link in w.select('a'):
        urls = link['href']
        print(urls)
        for url in urls:
            try:
                j=url.split('=')[1]
                k=  '/'.join(j.split('/')[0:4])
                print(k) 
            except:
                k = ''

Comment: code runs but I'm getting an empty result

Comment: That may not  relate to  the rule of  url split , may be data generating portion

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, and try to build a pattern that allows you to extract the information you need; for above example, following should work:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('https://.*?/.*?(?=/)',  p)
['https://www.facebook.com/bespokecatering.sydney']
```

The pattern `https://.*?/.*?(?=/)` captures everything from `https` before the second single `/`